# Cypress - Select button that contains text

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui, cypress

I'm using material-ui as my css framework and I want to select button that contains a specific text.
My current code:

```
cy.get('button').contains('Edit Claim').should('be.disabled');
```

It fails because the button component of material ui outputs the text inside a div so cypress is asserting the disabled attr to the div. I want it to assert to the button.

Edit:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

I solved it using `cy.contains('button', 'Edit Claim').should('be.disabled');`

Answer (score 4):

On the [Material-UI demo page](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/) the label is in a child `<span>` (not `<div>`),

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained Mui-disabled Mui-disabled" tabindex="-1" type="button" disabled="">
  <span class="MuiButton-label">Disabled</span>
</button>
```

but there may be variations - in any case, you can reference the button by adding `.parent()` to the test

```
cy.visit('https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/');
cy.get('button')
  .contains('Disabled')      // span is the subject
  .parent()                  // move up to the button
  .should('be.disabled');
```

Comment: It will select the parent elment which is a span. Material ui has a lot of elements nested inside a button thats the problem. Anyways I solved my problem ```cy.contains('button', 'Edit Claim').should('be.disabled');```

Comment: A better approach is to assign a `data-cy='btnX'` to the button and not to rely on text that may change in the future.
Later on you go like `cy.get('button[data-cy='btnX']).should('be.disabled')`

Comment: @BaltasarSolanilla Yes you are definitely correct but in our current setup I can only handle the testing

Comment: @BaltasarSolanilla if you wanna go this way, better to use `aria-label`, works in the same way and make your app better

Answer (score 0):

There might be the case 2 buttons have the same text then a better way is set `data-cy` property for that MUI button:

```
<Button data-cy="ok-btn">OK</Button>
```

then get it in cypress

```
cy.get('[data-cy="ok-btn"]').click();
```